# OCaml default include directory and default ocamlrun location

Tags: macos, ocaml, include-path, binaries, cross-build

I have compiled OCaml from source on my mac (the host), and I have no problem. I have also cross-compiled OCaml on my mac for some target (different from the host) and in this case I have the following issues :

1) I can use directly (on the target) `ocamlrun` and `ocamlyacc` as they are "pure" binaries, without problem, as on the host. If I want to use other binaries from `$INSTALL/bin` (`$INSTALL` is the install directory of `ocaml` on the target) like `ocamlopt`, I have errors telling my that the path of `ocamlrun` is wrong. Indeed, if I open the `ocamlopt` binary with and hexadecimal editor, I see that it begins with a `#!/not/target/but/host/path/to/ocamlrun` where the path is the path to `ocamlrun` on the host (my mac) on which I `configure`d the cross-build, not the path to its target version... Of course, if I replace this path by the one on the target, no need anymore to do `ocamlrun ocamlopt`, everything is ok. Same for all others binaries from `$INSTALL/bin`, `ocamlrun` and `ocamlyacc` put aside. (The last two do work directly, as I wrote above.) Is there a way to `configure` (on host) the `ocaml` cross-build so that the right path for `ocamlrun` on the target appears directly at beginning of binaries from `$INSTALL/bin` ?

2) I cannot compile code without needing to specify the `$INSTALL/lib/ocaml` dir through the `-I` flag. Is there a way to force this standard libraries path at the `configure` ? Or any `ocaml` "internal" environment variable dealing with it that I could edit to be sure that `ocaml` will look for libs in `$INSTALL/lib/ocaml` ? (I am quite pessimistic for an environment variable solution as on the host I only have two environment variables (at `printenv`) concerning `ocaml` and no one seems to deal with this kind of stuff, so that I don't see why it would go differently/better on the target...)

Comment: Do you have a reason to do this by hand instead of opam or even brew's version ocaml?

Comment: Yes, and a good one : there's no opam or brew on the target. (As you see in my question, I have an host, my mac, and a target, another os/machine.) So that I am forced to cross-build it, and before cross-building it, I wanted to build it (ocaml) from source to see/observe. (My vanilla ocaml I'm using on the host is not built from source btw, but installed with `opam.)

Comment: Have you already looked in [configure](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/configure) and tried the options such as [bindir](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/configure#L175) and libdir?